# Display values in a textbox or listbox c#

Tags: c#, class, dictionary, textbox, listbox

I am trying to display my values in a textbox or a listbox. I have a student class, main form, another form to add students. I was successful to add students into a dictionary and key is student Id, and there are other values(first name, last name, etc). Now I want to retrieve first name to a listbox or textbox. How can I do that?
I added a screen show to make it little bit clear.[image]

Comment: Where are you storing them ?

Comment: Dictionary objects are  created in both Main Form and other form. But from other form the values are passed to main form using a function. I am not sure is it the right way or not.

Comment: After application is closed you don't need this data ?

Comment: No I do not need the data after close. Need only until application runs. Thanks

Comment: Then create a static dictionary which will be available every where and persists data

Comment: Can you please explain it little further? Should I create it in main form or other form or the student class

Comment: It has to be in the main form, or a separate class. You can create a separate class like a repository and maintain all operations there

Comment: I was able to get some data from following code. But I am not sure how can I get all the data. because this code only allows to get last value.

`var line = StudentDic.Values.ElementAt(StudentDic.Count -1);
            allUniStudenTextBox.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, line.StudentFirstName);`

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Create a student class

```
public class Student
{
        public string StudentID { get; set; }
       public string StudentName { get; set; }
       //remaining properties 
}
```

Create repo

```
public static class StudentRepository
{
     private static List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
     public static void AddOrUpdateStudent(Student s)
     {
          var stu = students.Where(m=>m.StudentID = s.StudentID).FirstOrDefault();
           if(stu == null)
            {
                students.Add(s);
             }
             else
             {
                 students.remove(stu);
                 students.Add(s);
             }

     }
}
```

in the form use this as below

```
StudentRepository.AddOrUpdateStudent(s);
```